# how to multiply an int

Tags: java

How should I make a damage multiplier when someone has a block break on them?

I have used the following if-statement to make it happen:

```java
if(card.getEffects() == Cards.Effects.Block_Break) {
    packag.CustomDecks.cSet= Attack(int damage)*1.5;
}
```

*I misspeled `Attacks`*
but it doesn't recognize the keyword "damage".

This is my **Cards** class:

```java
public class Cards { 

    enum Effects {
        Return, Secret, Recover, Block_Break, Lifesteal, Burn, Paralyze, Reflect, Draw;
        
        private static final Effects[] effects = Effects.values();
        
        public static Effects getEffects(int i) {
            return Effects.effects[i];
        }
    }
 
    private final Effects effects;

    Cards(Effects effects) {
        this.effects = effects;
    }
    
    public Effects getEffects() {
        return this.effects;
    }
}
```

Another class **Attacks**:

```java
class Attacks extends Cards {

    public int damage;
    private final Effects effects;
    
    Attacks(int damage, final Effects effects) {
        super(effects);
        this.damage = damage;
        this.effects = effects; 
    }        
}
```

```
cSet = new ArrayList<CustomDecks>();
        Shuriken = new Attacks("Shuriken", 3, 2, packag.Effects.Return, packag.Cards.Classs.Wizard, packag.Cards.Rarity.Common, new ImageIcon("Shuriken.png"));
                
cSet.add(Shuriken);
```

this is cSet

Comment: You have to get `damage` a call where ever you're instantiating `Attack(...)`. For example: `int damage = 10; packag.CustomDecks.cSet = (new Attack(damage)).damage * 1.5;` You can also just do: `packag.CustomDecks.cSet = (new Attack(10)).damage * 1.5;`

Comment: Also when you multiply that `int` by 1.5 you're going to get a floating-point result, not an `int`.

Comment: 1) `Attack(int damage)` isn't valid usage of a constuctor. Your `Attacks` class constructor has two arguments, not one 2) You've also not shown any class called `Attack`, so what did you expect that to do? 3) `Attack` instance is what you're multiplying, not an int 4) What is the type of `cSet`?

Comment: Please explain the wanted "rounding" for `damage` and provide code showing declaration (exact type) of `CustomDecks.cSet` (you said _array_ of cards). Currently the if-statement and your expectation, so your question is unclear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you know: You can add properties to an `enum`.

### Define an enum with properties using a constructor

For example to add a **damage-multiplier** or **damage-factor** to each write:

```java
public enum Effects {
    Return(1),  // default factor is 1, which means no change
    Secret(1),
    Recover(1),
    Block_Break(1.5),  // multiplier added here
    Lifesteal(1),
    Burn(1),
    Paralyze(1),
    Reflect(1),
    Draw(1);

    private final double damageFactor;

    // constructor to associate a damage-multiplier to each Effect
    Effects(double damageFactor) {
        this.damageFactor = damageFactor;
    }
    
    // you need a getter to use the factor outside
    public double getDamageFactor() {
        return this.damageFactor;
    }

    private static final Effects[] effects = Effects.values();
    public static Effects getEffects(int i) {
            return Effects.effects[i];
    }
}
```

Then you could simply use it to apply Effect-specific damage like this:

```java
    // typo:  assume the class name is "Attack" not "Attacks"
    Attack(int damage, final Effects effects) {
        super(effects);
        // final damage is a combination of effect-factor multiplied specified damage
        this.damage = (int) Math.round(damage * effects.getDamageFactor()); // round to int, e.g. 3 * 1.5 = 4.5; rounded to 5
        this.effects = effects; 
    }
```

### The if-statement leads to compile-error(s)

```java
if(card.getEffects() == Cards.Effects.Block_Break) {
    packag.CustomDecks.cSet= Attack(int damage)*1.5;
}
```

What you gave as if-statement will lead to a compile-error, because

- Class not found: there is no class (hence no constructor) called `Attack`. The class given is named in plural: `Attacks` (ending with `s`!).
- Syntax-Error: to call a constructor with `new` (forgot that keyword!) simply pass a variable like `myDamage` (no `int` as type-declaration needed!)
- Constructor not found: the constructor of `Attack` requires currently 2 arguments: `int damage` and `Effects effects`. But you only passed the first.
- Type-Error: the `new Attack` object can not be multiplied with a double like `1.5`

Not sure if `packag.CustomDecks.cSet` is correct.

#### Fix the syntax errors

To fix it, you could correct like that:

```java
int myDamage = 10;
if (card.getEffects() == Cards.Effects.Block_Break) {
    // prefix with new, int multiplication, pass 2nd param
    packag.CustomDecks.cSet = new Attack(myDamage * 2, Cards.Effects.Block_Break); // will init damage with 20
}
```

Or - with the new constructor from above - you can make use of the effect passed in:

```java
packag.CustomDecks.cSet = new Attack(damage, card.getEffects()); // *1.5: is done inside using factor bound to current effect
```

Note: No if is needed then. The factor is constantly pulled from current effect.

### Naming Convention commonly used in Java

**Class Names:**

Usually classes in Java are named in singular, unless they are collections containing many items.

**Enums:**

Also the enum class would be named `Effect` (singular) by convention. Because an enum defines a set of constants. But an enum variable like the field in your class `Attacks` represents a single state and value, for example the state `Block_Break`.

The enum-values are usually written in uppercase with underscores separating words like `BLOCK_BREAK`. It's the same naming-convention like for constants, because enum-values are constants.